# Login to get username not email

Tags: php, html, email

I've been struggling to get the username after login using email. I can managed to get the the name of email but not username after logged in.

Look at the code for login.php below:

```
<form id="myForm" action="loginAction" name="login" method="POST">  
            <p> <label class="inputField" > Email Address : </label> </p>
            <p> <input class="registerField" id="emailid" name="email" required="required" type="text" placeholder="eg. john.wick@yahoo.com"/> <span class="warning" id="emailWarning"> </p>

            <p> <label class="inputField" > Password : </label> </p>
            <p> <input class="registerField" id="password" name="password" required="required" type="password" placeholder="Your password"/> </p>

            <p> <input name="submit" class="registerButton" type="submit" value="LOGIN"> </p>
        </form>
```

The action will go to loginAction.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($username);
    $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password);

    $salt = sha1(md5($password));
    $epwd = md5($password.$salt);

    $loginUser = "  SELECT registerPassword, emailAddress, firstName, lastName FROM register_user
                    WHERE emailAddress = '$username' AND registerPassword = '$epwd'";

    $loginSuccess = mysqli_query($mysqli, $loginUser) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
    $loginRow = mysqli_num_rows($loginSuccess);

    if($loginRow === 1) {

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        if ($_SESSION['login'] != '' || $_SESSION['login'] > 0 )

        echo $_SESSION['username'];
        echo $_SESSION['firstName'];
        echo $_SESSION['lastName'];

        header ("Location: index");
        } else {
            header ("Location: loginRegError");
        }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

And when it succeed login, it will go to this page below

```
<?php
                ini_set('display_errors',1); 
                error_reporting(E_ALL);
                include 'dbconnect.php';

                if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'] )) {
                    $firstName = $_SESSION['firstName'];

                    echo "<p> <a href=\"profileUser\"> $firstName </a>";
                    echo "<img src=\"images/logo/account.png\" /> </p>";
                        } else {
                        echo "<a href=\"loginReg\"> Login/Register </a>";
                        echo "<img src=\"images/logo/account.png\" /> </p>";
                    }
            ?>
```

The error shows **Notice: Undefined index: firstName**. If i use `$_SESSION` for email, it worked, but i want to show first name of user. Any idea?

Comment: where did you assign `$_SESSION['firstName'];`?

Comment: It is at the bottom in **loginAction.php**. @itachi

Comment: i don't see any line above where you assigned it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `loginAction.php`, `$_SESSION['firstName']` is not assigned. Thats why later on after redirection, its not set so trying to access it would give the undefined index error.

It might be better to just save the user info row instead if you want to later access it:

```
$loginSuccess = mysqli_query($mysqli, $loginUser) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
$loginRow = mysqli_num_rows($loginSuccess);

if($loginRow === 1) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    // fetch the values
    $user_info = $loginSuccess->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['user_info'] = $user_info; // assign that row in the session for later use
```

Then after on that redirection page:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

    echo $_SESSION['user_info']['firstName'];
    // and others

}
```

Sidenote: Also its much better to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) on this case, and use [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php) of PHP 5.5 instead of md5. There is also a [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) for lesser versions (PHP <= 5.4)

Comment: Yes it is very well explained, i'm trying to use this answer, but still i don't get it. Well, i'm going to fetch values for `firstName` and `lastName`, where should I add it? i should just put `$_SESSION[firstName] = $firstName` after `$_SESSION['user_info']`? @Ghost

Comment: @Anthosiast since this `$user_info` will hold those values `registerPassword, emailAddress, firstName, lastName`. well there is no reason to assign each. its an array already. access those values along with that example i gave above. `echo $_SESSION['user_info']['lastName']; // and others`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks man, on the way to lah lah land soon, just making the best out of time before going :D

Comment: Hey mate! it works well. thank you for that. Now i get what `fetch_assoc` means. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @Ghost just came back from there myself lol *Cheers*

Comment: @Anthosiast thats just an object oriented interface, since its just my personal preference, but its the same as `mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginSuccess)`. glad this helped

Comment: nah yeah `mysqli_fetch_assoc($loginSuccess)` is better, It can stick on my mind easily :)

Comment: @Anthosiast yeah you can choose either that or the other one as mysqli has support on both procedural and object oriented interface. if thats what you like then its okay no problem with that.

Comment: @Ghost anyway, I'm trying to use `fetch_assoc` for register as well. It doesn't work there? after I'm using `$_SESSION['userinfo']['firstName']`. After i registered, it doesn't show any name there.. Would you mind to help me more?

Comment: @Anthosiast when you're are inserting, you do not need that, that is used for selecting rows

Comment: @Ghost yes, you are right. I'm inserting user information, however, `$user_info` are still in `index.php`. I need `$user_info` for login. How to get rid of it if I have successfully registered?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64577/discussion-between-anthosiast-and-ghost).

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
    $_SESSION['login'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    if ($_SESSION['login'] != '' || $_SESSION['login'] > 0 )

    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    echo $_SESSION['firstName'];
    echo $_SESSION['lastName'];
```

you try to Output `$_SESSION['firstName']` but `$_SESSION['firstName']` Does not exist.

you set `$_SESSION['username']=$username` (i think $username was the email only)
but you dont set `$_SESSION['firstName']`

fetch you loginrow and set `$_SESSION['firstName']=$fetchedRow['firstName'];`

Comment: thank you guys, I've make it worked, i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

What you're storing in the session variable is $username which equals the input the user sent to you. You're defining only $_SESSION['username'], leaving firstName and lastName undefined. If I understand what you want to do correctly, you'll have to fetch the result from your database query and store it on those variables.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. you can improve the quality of your answer by adding code snippets (like the other answers). it will be more helpful then.